# A car drives north, then east, then southwest. Find the displacement and average velocity

Tags: geometry, physics, vectors

A car drives north at 36mi/h  for 10 min  and then turns east and goes 5.0 mi  at 66mi/h  . Finally, it goes southwest at 32mi/h  for 6.0 min.

Find the car's displacement and find the average velocity for the trip.
Both is in x & y components.

I'm having a really hard time all around with this question. i drew a triangle, but not sure which components are x and which are y

Comment: For the displacement, you just need to find the displacement in each component (x and y) separately. To do this, find and use the x and y components of each velocity (using trigonometry if needed).

Comment: If you draw a diagram of the trip, you won't get an obvious triangle - think of the diagram as a map.

Comment: If you drew a triangle, why don't you show it to us? Otherwise we don't know what triangle you drew or whether it is the right one.

Comment: What's with all of the downvotes?

Comment: @user7530 Bad LaTeX / bad effort / wrong site.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment question should be considered incomplete without specifying which cardinal direction corresponds to $x$ and which to $y$, but the most common convention I've seen is that $\bf\hat{x}$ points east and $\bf\hat{y}$ points north.

Comment: ok yeah those are the directions!!